# Bootstrap 3.3 with global left-offset content overflowing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want both my main content area and the first element of my navbar to start offset from the left by `2rem`. However, this is causing me a lot of headache with child columns.

I can't figure out how to add a global offset of `2rem`, without also having to change all calculations of child columns to account for the change. Example:

```
<div class="row">
  <!-- outer content div to offset all content elements --> 
  <div class"col-lg-offset-2">
    <div class="row">

      <!-- shouldn't this refer to the inner row? -->
      <div class="col-lg-6>
        This is 6
      </div> 
      <div class="col-lg-6>
        And 6 more...and content is getting cut-off from the right
      </div> 

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I was hoping to get, is to continue using all child divs width settings the same and to have their size compared relative to their new parent width, which is 2rem less (or to the left).

Comment: Are you trying to center the content?

Comment: @Miaan no. Only offset by a consistent distance.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you should set the size when setting offset.  So if you offset your `.col-lg-*` with `x`, then you should also reduce the size of it with `x`.

See my example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="main" class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-10">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
          This is 6
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
          And 6 more...and content is not gettin cut-off from the right
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So what I did, was to offset the div `#main`, but I also made the size smaller to compensate for the offset.  Say the offset is by 2 cols, so the size was also made less by 2 cols.  So instead of `col-xs-12` taking the entire with, `col-xs-10` no takes the entire width because it has an offset of 2 cols.

Answer (score 0):

Like @jae.phoenix already said columns within a row should always add up to 12. So when you offset the column by 2 the other column should take the other 10 unless you want to center it then you should keep in mind "2" offset should be taken from the other side that would leave 8. Offset also stays with the column meaning if it is applied in the xs size it will be applied to all sizes above it example sm md lg xlg; SO keep that in mind. here is my answer:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                This is 6
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                And 6 more...and content is not gettin cut-off from the right
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Keeping the column to start offset as sm rather that xs leaving some room when screen size gets to small. Hope this helps.